# Multiple threads awaiting Task if it is already running

Tags: c#

I have app which have different timers running in the background doing synchronization with the API.

However, before the actual sync they all ping the API whether they can proceed or not. In order to not make multiple calls, I've made them await the same `Task` if it is already running. After the result comes from the task those who await should get the result and in the mean time if there is a call to the `CanExecute` method and the `Task` is not running it should rerun the `Task` and so on.

```
protected async Task<bool> CanExecute([CallerMemberName] string memberName = "")
{
    lock (_lockobj)
    {
        if (_runningTask == null)
        {
           _runningTask = CanExecuteTask(memberName);
        }
    }

    var result = await _runningTask;
    _runningTask = null;
    return result;
}

private async Task<bool> CanExecuteTask(string callingMemberName)
{
    var result = // do http call and some other method calls
    return result;
}
```

I'm not sure what the problem is, but I think it happens to deadlock and the synchronization doesn't proceed. What is the proper way to achieve that?

Comment: Do you really need to call `CanExecute` lazily? If not, you can call ` _runningTask = CanExecuteTask` in the constructor and `await` in the method. The task will only start once but every thread will await until it compeltes

Comment: Can you try to use the SemaphoreSlim  class instead of the lock in your  CanExecuteTask?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it's possible, but will the `Task` re-run if it is already Completed when a thread happens to await it?

Comment: `await` awaits an already active task, it doesn't cause it to start. Task aren't threads or functions. They represent a *promise* that something may complete and produce a value in the future. It's a common idiom to start a task in the constructor and store it in a field.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos exactly. What I need is the Task to be called again if it has completed or not started at all. In that case I don't know how lazy initialization would help me.

Comment: That's not what the question asked. There's an out-of-the-box solution if you use a [Bounded channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel.createbounded?view=net-7.0) with capacity=1 and [FullMode = DropWrite or DropNewest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.boundedchannelfullmode?view=net-7.0). This will ensure that any attempts to post anything to the channel's worker will be discarded if the worker is already busy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written this code is not safe - you both read and write `_runningTask` outside of the lock. So for example, one thread can execute

```
_runningTask = null;
```

While another thread just got past the lock statement while task was not null and is about to execute `await _runningTask`. This will result in `await null` so in `NullReferenceException`.

You can avoid that while keeping the same principle by doing this:

```
private Task<bool> _runningTask = Task.FromResult(false);
protected async Task<bool> CanExecute([CallerMemberName] string memberName = "") {
    Task<bool> task;
    lock (_lockobj) {
        if (_runningTask.IsCompleted) {
            _runningTask = CanExecuteTask(memberName);
        }
        task = _runningTask;
    }

    var result = await task;        
    return result;
}
```

Instead of setting task to null and then checking that - we check if task has been completed (which means succeeded, faulted, or cancelled). We then also start with already completed task instead of null.

Also we assign `_runningTask` to local variable inside the lock, and then await that, to avoid reading `_runningTask` field outside of the lock.

Awaiting the same task from multiple threads is safe, so we should be fine here.